# linux command to fetch path of S3

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have S3 bucket path like

`s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar`

I want to fetch all characters after first "/" (not //) and before last "/" .
So here output should be

```
apyong/output/public
```

I tried `awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'` .But its not producing correct results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `sed` solution:

```bash
s='s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar'
sed -E 's~.*//[^/]*/|/[^/]*$~~g' <<< "$s"

apyong/output/public
```

Pure bash solution:

```bash
s='s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar'
r="${s#*//*/}"
echo "${r%/*}"

apyong/output/public
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `grep` you could use following solution. Using `-oP` options with GNU `grep` will make sure it prints only matched values and enables PCRE regex respectively. Then in main `grep` code using regex `^.*?\/\/.*?\/\K(.*)(?=/)`(explained following) to fetch the desired outcome.

```bash
var="s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar"
grep -oP '^.*?\/\/.*?\/\K(.*)(?=/)' <<<"$var"

apyong/output/public
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex.

```bash
^.*?\/\/  ##From starting of value performing a lazy match till // here.
.*?\/     ##again performing lazy match till single / here.
\K        ##\K will make sure previous values are forgotten in order to print only needed values.
(.*)(?=/) ##This is greedy match to get everything else as per requirement.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` please try following code. Using capturing group capability of GNU `awk` here to store values captured by regex in array arr to be used later on in program.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^[^:]*:\/\/[^/]*\/(.*)\//,arr){print arr[1]}' <<<"$var"
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** `awk`'s `match` + `match` solution here to get the required output.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^[^:]*:\/\/[^/]*\//) && match(val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH),/^.*\//){
  print substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
}
' <<<"$var"
```

Comment: @AWS_Lernar, Good that you have accepted an answer. You could also check answers from other users and could let them know how their answers went, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F "/" '{ for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) { if (i==4) { printf "%s",$i } else { printf "/%s",$i } }}' <<< "s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar"
```

Set the field delimiter to "/" and the look through the 4th to the last field. For the fourth field print the field and for all other field print "/" then the field.

Answer (score 0):

Use coreutils `cut`:

```
<<<"s3://my-dev-s3/apyong/output/public/file3.gz.tar" \
cut -d/ -f4-6
```

Output:

```
apyong/output/public
```